# IIS maximum requests per second on 8 Core, 15 GB RAM Server

Tags: iis-8, iis-8.5

Currently I am using AWS EC2 servers to get maximum requests per second on server. I am using two EC2 8 Core, 15 GB Servers with AWS load balancer and backend database as Sql server with 8 Core and 30 GB Server. I have ASP.net WebAPI's deployed on IIS Server and tested load testing with JMeter. With current settings I am getting 1650 requests per second and CPU on servers are showing 20-30% utilization.

Can any body suggest me settings on IIS server to get maximum requests per second, we are targeting 3000 requests per second.

We are using Windows 2012 Server and IIS 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question! that will entirely depend on your situation. If you have load testing configured the best way to improve performance is to make adjustments and test the results.

However the mostly likely source of improvement will come from rewriting your application. By using profiling to understand where the bottlenecks are and making the work the server needs to do as small as possible. So offloading work to middleware servers and perhaps caching (if that is possible)

Performance tuning is always an iterative process, you understand what is in the way of your application performing faster and do something to improve it, then test to see if it actually did improve. Rinse. Repeat.

Have you tried running 4 4 core servers instead of 2x8? if your CPU utilisation is that low. At the very least it will provide you with some more answers as to where your bottleneck is.

Comment: Thank you Michael. We are using Caching for faster retrieval. I could see bottleneck on IIS Server. I haven't tried with 2X4 core servers.